# Generating div,ul,li,a tag combination dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

My Jade!
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-hzRqciA1Tjs/UGmc39ijHuI/AAAAAAAAAFk/0XJzY0ZqU70/s720/App.jpg

```
div(data-role='content')
   div(class='content-primary')
      ul(data-role="listview", data-split-theme='a',data-split-icon='gear')
         li(data-theme='a')
          a(href="")
            div(id='addClientDivId')
          a(href='#', data-icon='delete', title=' Delete ')
```

I wanna generate the above jade contents dynamically using jquery.
Can anyone help me..???

As i dont have reputation, I have uploaded a image screenshot to picasa.Refer the screenshot. I have tried all the possibilities given below, but couldn get the effects as on the screenshot.

Answer:

I have found solution for my query.

```
var newContent = '<div data-role="content" data-theme="a" class="content-primary">';
        newContent += '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true" id="ulId">';
        newContent += '<li>';
        newContent += '<a href="">';
        newContent += '<h4></h4>';
        newContent += '<h5></h5>';
        newContent += '<a href="" , data-icon="delete">';
        newContent += '</a>';
        newContent += '</a>';
        newContent += '</li>';
        newContent += '</ul>';
        newContent += '</div>';
        $("#addClientDivId").append(newContent).trigger('create');
```

Comment: To start off with http://whathaveyoutried.com, then http://jquery.com, then if you are still struggling, come back here and ask a proper question.

Comment: I have tried to create a div dynamically using jquery. I wanna append a ul,li, and an anchor tag to that div.So every time i create a div dynamically it ll be created inside a ul,li,a tags respectively. Also I want all the data role's to be applied dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You could either build each tag as a separate jQuery object:

```
var contentDiv = $('<div></div>').attr('data-role','content');
var contentPrimary = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'content-primary');
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
$(ul).attr('data-role', 'listview').attr('data-split-theme', 'a').attr('data-split-icon','gear');
```

Then add your li(s) to your ul ..

```
for(..) {
   var li = $('<li></li>');
   var liContent = $('<a></a>').attr('href', 'a');
   // You can build the rest of your li content here.

   // Append the li content to the li
   $(li).append(liContent);

   // And then append the li to the ul
   $(ul).append(li);
}
```

Once done with the ul you can compose the rest.

```
$(contentPrimary).append(ul);
$(contentDiv).append(contentPrimary);
```

Then add everything to the DOM, let's say inside the body

```
$('body').append(contentDiv);
```

To make things more performant you could, build your entire structure as a string (concat with '+') and then add it to the DOM.

```
var contentDivAsString = '<div data-role="content">....</div>';
$('body').append($(contentDivAsString));
```

Either approach would work, just the second one would be more performant and you'd use less objects to accomplish it.

Comment: I have tried something like this.... But my data-role theme , href and all not reflecting....                                                                       var content = '<div data-role="content"><div class="content-primary"><ul data-role="listview", data-split-theme="a",data-split-icon="gear"><li data-theme="a"><a href=""></a><h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+$('#clientName').val()+'</h4><p><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+status+'</p></p><a href="#", data-icon="delete", title="Delete"></a></li></ul></div></div>'

Comment: $("<div/>", { "class":"ui-body-a", id:"product"+i})
 .append($(content))
 .appendTo("#addClientDivId");
 i++;

Comment: It looks like you have some commas in between your attributes, besides that it's not really clear to me what are you trying to accomplish exactly. If you follow my first example you should be able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the html in a string like this one: `content = "<div data-role='content'">[...]</div>` and if you want to just add it to the body `$("body").append(content)`

Otherwise check out the documentation about selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var aMain=$('<a/>', {
    'text':'Delete',
    'href':'',
    'data-icon':'delete',
    'title':' Delete '
});
var acDivid=$('<div id="addClientDivId"></div>');
var a=$('<a href=""></a>');
var li=$('<li data-theme="a"></li>');
var ul=$('<ul />', {
   'data-role':'listview',
   'data-split-theme':'a',
   'data-split-icon':'gear'
});
var cP=$('<div class="content-primary"></div>');
var content=$('<div data-role="content"></div>');
$('body').append(content.append(cP.append(ul.append(li.append(a.append(acDivid.append(aMain)))))));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/awaded/1/edit).